# Contextual key mappings in PyCharm on macOS

Tags: macos, keybindings

For years I've been using a keymap (IIRC carried over from Visual Studio circa 2005) where <kbd>F5</kbd> is the same key for "debug..." and "resume program". However while setting up my latest installation on macOS, setting both actions to <kbd>F5</kbd> only brings up the "debug..." menu instead of resuming the program. How can I configure pycharm to use the same key for "debug..." when no program is running and "resume program" when a program is running?

Is there an existing keymap that has this set? I can't seem to find the built-in or downloaded keymap I was using on my previous setup but I don't think I customized any of the mappings. Pycharm version 2021.2.2 Professional.

Comment: Which version of macOS and pecharm are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer by accident. It turns out that if you assign <kbd>F5</kbd> to `Resume Program`, by default it brings up the same menu as `debug...`. My issue was that by assigning both to <kbd>F5</kbd>, the `Resume Program` function was being overridden while in a debug or run state.